# disable alsa cards

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I'm getting 3 cards back when I do run this :

```
cat /proc/asound/cards

 0 [Headphones     ]: bcm2835_headpho - bcm2835 Headphones
                      bcm2835 Headphones
 1 [vc4hdmi        ]: vc4-hdmi - vc4-hdmi
                      vc4-hdmi
 2 [sndrpihifiberry]: RPi-simple - snd_rpi_hifiberry_amp
                      snd_rpi_hifiberry_amp
```

I would like to disable 0 and 1, so that 2 becomes 0, and remains 0 forever.

how can I achieve this ?

thanks ! :)

Comment: You could try blacklisting the modules responsible for the cards. If they are built-in it becomes a lot more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to achieve is (as worded in the title) disable alsa sound devices then blacklisting their modules is actually the way to go.

But, reading your question, I understand that you are in fact bothered by the ids given by the system.
You should be able to force some particular order by simply adding lines to your `/etc/modprobe.d/sound` file. In your particular case, only one looking like

```
options snd_rpi_hifiberry_amp index=0
```

should suffice.

In case your module also manages the two other devices, (like the snd_hda-intel) you can then write instead :

```
options snd_rpi_hifiberry_amp index=2,1,0
```

BTW, if you are only bothered by the fact Alsa is (per default) using device 0 as default, be aware that you just can change this by only fiddling your $HOME/.asoundrc or /etc/asound.conf with 3 lines of the kind :

```
defaults.ctl.card 2
defaults.pcm.card 2
defaults.pcm.device 0
```

or adapt your existing configuration if default already defined.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Fixing the index is indeed  way to go !